A question about a point of a curve with positive curvature

Let $I=(a,b) \subset \Bbb{R}$, $\alpha \in C^{\infty} (I, \Bbb{R}^2)$ a natural curve (that is, $\forall t \in I : \lVert \alpha ' (t) \rVert = 1 $ ) and $s_0 \in I$ such that $\kappa_\alpha (s_0) > 0 $. Then, there is a neighbourhood $J \subset I$ of $s_0$ such that $\alpha(J) \subset \Pi _N $ where $\Pi _N$ is the semiplane generated by the tangent line at $\alpha (s_0)$ where $N_\alpha (s_0)$ points at.

I am trying to solve this excercise from my Geometry Differential notes but I am getting stuck and I want to know if I am doing well. I denote the tangent and normal vector of $\alpha$ by $T_\alpha$ and $N_\alpha$  respectively.
The tangent line at $s_0$ is $r = \{ p \in \Bbb{R}^2 : \det (p - \alpha (s_0), T_\alpha(s_o)) = 0 \} $ . Therefore, we have two semiplanes: $\Pi_1 = \{ p \in \Bbb{R}^2 : \det (p - \alpha (s_0), T_\alpha(s_o)) < 0 \} $ and $ \Pi_2 = \{ p \in \Bbb{R}^2 : \det (p - \alpha (s_0), T_\alpha(s_o)) > 0 \} $ .
The semiplane where $N_\alpha(s_0)$ points at is in which $\alpha(s_0) + N_\alpha(s_0)$ is contained. Since $\det (\alpha(s_0) + N_\alpha(s_0) - \alpha (s_0), T_\alpha(s_o)) = \det (N_\alpha(s_0), T_\alpha(s_0)) = - \lVert \alpha(s_0) \rVert = -1$ , we can conclude that $\Pi_N = \Pi_1 $ .
My idea now was to define $f: I \rightarrow \Bbb{R}, t \mapsto \det ( \alpha(t) - \alpha(s_0) , T_\alpha(s_0)) $ which is a continuous function and use results from Real analysis to prove the existence of $J$ but I am not getting how to finish it and how to use the sign of $\kappa_\alpha(s_0)$ so any possible help or advice would be appreciated.

I suggest you prove that $f$ has a local maximum at $t=s_0$ by finding $f'(t)$ for $t$ in a neighborhood of $s_0$. It will follow that $f$ is negative in that neighborhood.

@GReyes Thanks! That helps a lot :)
